# Create classes and structs to represent JSON objects in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm attempting to create classes that correspond to JSON data retrieved in Swift. For nested objects, is it suitable to represent them via structs rather than separate classes? Or should these simply be treated as dictionary objects? So for example below is some JSON:

```
{
  prop1: value1,
  prop2: {
    subprop1: subvalue1,
    subprop2: subvalue2
  }
}
```

What would be the best way to represent the nested `prop2` object in a Swift class? I'm currently doing so using structs as follows:

```
class MyClass {
  struct prop2 {
    var subprop1: AnyObject?
    var subprop2: AnyObject?
  }

  var prop1: AnyObject?
}
```

This method becomes a bit cumbersome, however, when there are deeply nested objects so not sure how best to handle those cases.

I'll also add that I have no problem serializing the data into NSDictonary objects like so:

```
if let details: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary { }
```

However, I'm trying to take this one step further and map the dictionary's properties to their respective class variables/structs in Swift.

Comment: Checkout the [JSONModel Project](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel#model-collections), it looks good.

Comment: looks interesting although no Swift support as required in the question

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward to get native NSDictionary objects from JSON passed into the [NSJSONSerialization class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010946-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1), and if you set up your JSON representation in a well formed NSDictionary object, you can do the reverse (that is, you can create a JSON data stream from a NSDictonary object), via the [`dataWithJSONObject:options:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/dataWithJSONObject:options:error:) API.

The public documentation is for Objective-C, but if you log into Apple's Developer Portal, you can also look up the pre-release Swift documentation as well.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I've managed to serialize the JSON data in to NSDictionary objects as such:

if let imageDetails: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

However this doesn't quite accomplish 100% of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a custom JSON deserialization framework taking inspiration from [this article](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/efficient-json-in-swift-with-functional-concepts-and-generics).

Next, I'd create an interface like this:

```
protocol JsonDeserializable {
    typealias T
    class func deserialize(json: NSDictionary) -> T
}
```

and a hierarchy of either classes or structs, avoiding nested structs so to make them reusable:

```
struct MyStruct1 : JsonDeserializable {
    var prop1: Type1
    var prop2: MyStruct2

    static func deserialize(json: NSDictionary) -> MyStruct1 {
        ...
    }
}

struct MyStruct2 : JsonDeserializable {
    var subprop1: Subtype1
    var subprop2: Subtype2

    static func deserialize(json: NSDictionary) -> MyStruct2 {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have expanded upon the ideas on that blog post and created an open-source library that you might want to check out as well: https://github.com/isair/JSONHelper#json-string-deserialization

It even supports deserializing JSON strings directly into objects with one line (or an array of objects still in one line).